# VSCode extension: remove all indentation with language-configuration rule

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, vscode-extensions, auto-indent

I am wondering whether it is possible for a **VSCode extension** to have an unindent rule that removes all indentation when there is a regex match. I can specify indentation rules in a [language-configuration.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#indentation-rules) file but `decreaseIndentPattern` only decreases indentation by 1. (Also, I wouldn't want all the other `decreaseIndentPattern`s to drop all their indentations.)

### Example

Normally what you get is this

```
program main
      integer :: a
      #ifdef DEBUG
      integer :: b
      #endif
end program main
```

which is not compilable code for Fortran so you have to manually indent the preprocessor directives (lines starting with `#`).

Ideally, what I would want is when typing the `#` character in VSCode, to drop all indentation for that line.

```
program main
      integer :: a
#ifdef DEBUG  ! the # character should drop all indentation only for this line
      integer :: b
#endif
end program main
```

Comment: Did you try `unIndentedLinePattern` ?

Comment: `unIndentedLinePattern` does not work since it leaves the indentation unchanged for the line.
>unIndentedLinePattern - If a line matches this pattern, then its indentation should not be changed and it should not be evaluated against the other rules.